# How to set hAxis as date format in Google Chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I use Google Chart as DataTable.
I try to make `hAxis` like as date format:

```
hAxis: {
            title: '',
            format: 'date',
            viewWindow: {
                min: [7, 30, 0],
                max: [17, 30, 0]
            }
        }
```

And add rows as:

```
data.addRows([
        [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '03/02/13'}, 1],
        [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '04/02/13'}, 2],
        [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'05/02/13'}, 3],
        [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '06/02/13'}, 4],
        [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '07/02/13'}, 5]
    ]);
```

I need to get in horizontal line(hAxis) titles in date format: `dd/mm/yy`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters

Comment: Oh. I see now. Your values are probably interpreted as Time of Day, not Date. You need to pass a javascript Date object to have the charts library format it as a Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hAxis.format` expects a pattern, or pattern name
so it would be something like...

```
hAxis: {
  format: 'short'
  // or
  format: 'dd/MM/yy'
}
```

however, as pointed out in the comments, the column type appears to be `timeofday`

to avoid changing the column type, you can provide your own custom `hAxis.ticks`,
using the data provided to the chart

see following, working snippet. uses `rawData` to populate chart data and ticks...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var rawData = [
        [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '03/02/13'}, 1],
        [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '04/02/13'}, 2],
        [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'05/02/13'}, 3],
        [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '06/02/13'}, 4],
        [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '07/02/13'}, 5]
    ];

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn({label: 'Date', type: 'timeofday'});
    data.addColumn({label: 'Count', type: 'number'});
    data.addRows(rawData);

    var hTicks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
      hTicks.push(rawData[i][0]);
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      hAxis: {
          ticks: hTicks,
          title: '',
          viewWindow: {
              min: [7, 30, 0],
              max: [17, 30, 0]
          }
      }
    });
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```